# How to direct all requests to index.php in sublocation in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Part of config:

```
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
            auth_basic off;
    }
```

When I request `http://myserver.com/any/url` - it prompts with http password. It's ok.

But when I request `http://myserver.com/api/anything` I do not want to make password prompt.

Error in log:

```
"/var/www/public/api/anything" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 1.2.3.4
```

But actually request must go to "/var/www/public/index.php". Why it does not hit index.php?

Comment: You need to execute the `index.php` from inside the `location ^~ /api` block. Show the part of your config that includes `location \.php$ { ... }` if you want more help.

Comment: Solved it.

     location ^~ /api {
         auth_basic off;
         try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
     }

  location / {
        auth_basic           "closed site";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
   
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

Problem was: `auth_basic` directive was `outside` of any location block.

Comment: So none of your PHP files are protected now then.

Comment: Actually, not.

Only `/api/*` urls are not protected.

Comment: Have you tested that?

Comment: Yes. I opened my browser in incognito and checked different urls.